# validate email address with Python

Tags: python, validation

I'm trying to validate emails using [validate_email 1.3 : Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email), like this:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',check_mx=True)
```

How can I speed this up? My `for` loop isn't very effective with amount of emails I need to verify...

Comment: I think speeding this up is rather impossible since `check_mx` checks every SMTP-server by trying to establish a connection to it wich takes some time. However, since this is a so called I/O-bound process you can try to use different threads in parallel.

Comment: Do you just want to validate that the string _looks like_ a proper email address, or do you need to verify that the email account actually exists?

Comment: I need to verify `MX` record as well, I'm thinking of "multithreading" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only use `check_mx=True` the first time you encounter a domain. After that, just use a regex to validate the address.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: If I to use `verify=False` in addition to `check_mx=True`, your solution wouldn't work.